# How to include JPA converter from an external library into a Spring boot project?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I would like to put in my maven library an Email class used in several Spring boot projects. So I have gather in my lib:

```kotlin
class Email(val value: String)

@JsonComponent
class EmailSerializer : JsonSerializer<Email>()

@JsonComponent
class EmailDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<Email>()

@Converter(autoApply = true)
class EmailConverter : AttributeConverter<Email, String>

@Configuration
@Import(value = [EmailSerializer::class, EmailDeserializer::class, EmailConverter::class])
class EmailConfiguration
```

In my project then I can include them all at once:

```kotlin
@Configuration
@Import(value = [EmailConfiguration::class])
class ApplicationConfiguration
```

Since, the JsonComponents are well imported, but I have failed to configure correctly my spring project in order to auto apply the EmailConverter. I still have to apply it explicitely:

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
class User(
    @Convert(converter = EmailConverter::class)
    var email: Email,
)
```

else I get this error: `org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.betomorrow.commons.components.Email, at table: user, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(email)]`

Since `@Converter` does not make the class a Component, I tried to add `@Component` and `@Configurable` and also without the `EmailConfiguration` class but with a `ComponentScan("myPackage")`, but still the same.

Any idea ? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have ak relationship email ?

Comment: @Zaur, sorry I don't understand what you mean by "ak relationship".

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the converter as a Spring bean like so (in class annotated with @Configuration:

```
@Bean 
public MyConverter myconverter() {
  return new MyConverter();
}
```

Comment: If you mean to do just like that, it does not work better.

```
@Configuration
@Import(value = [EmailSerializer::class, EmailDeserializer::class])
class EmailConfiguration{
    @Bean
    fun emailConverterBean(): EmailConverter {
        return EmailConverter()
    }
}
```